# Bootstrap hover popover stops working after click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a bootstrap popover defined in `<th>` tag like this:

```
<div class="thead-popover" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-placement="top" 
    data-container="body" 
    data-trigger="hover" 
    data-html="true" 
    data-content="very nice content"
    title="Nice title with <span>html tag</span>" >
Info
</div>
```

Initializing popover in Marionette/Backbone/Rails/coffeescript application like this:

```
onCompositeCollectionRendered: ->
  @$('.thead-popover').popover()
```

Popover works like expected (on hover) but if I click on `<div>` element it stops working. Even if I initialize it once again it will not work. No errors. Also tried playing with data-attributes with no luck. I don't have any listeners on `<div>` click events. Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code, I guess you have some click event handlers defined?

Comment: Works the same way with `<div>` and there are no click event listeners on that

Comment: Show you code anyway, because your setup is fine.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot :( It kinda big application. But I added more information on how I call popover

Comment: Well try to isolate the problem, maybe creating a demo. Otherwise it's hard to help you, as above code is just fine.

Comment: What browser(s) does this happen with?

Comment: Mozilla and Chromium both